# How link <i> tags to change text simultaneously onclick?

Tags: jquery, indexing, onclick

Here's what I got so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('.alt').click(function () {
    var index = $(this).attr("data-text-index");
    var text = $.parseJSON($(this).attr("data-text"));
    if (index == null) index = -1;
    index = Number(index) + 1 >= text.length ? 0 : Number(index) + 1;
    $(this).html(text[index]);
    $(this).attr("data-text-index", index);
});

$('.alt').click();

});
```

Example HTML:

```
I <i class="alt" id="text1a" data-text='["like","love","am fond of"]'></i> <i class="alt" id="text1b" data-text='["her","you"]'></i>, but I don't know <i class="alt" id="text2" data-text='["him","you"]'></i>.
```

I need the function to run for all elements of class "alt" onload, so that each populates with the first text in its data-index. Then, upon clicking the first or second i tag (id="text1a" or "text1b"), I want both to cycle to the next text in their data-text group, while the third i tag (id="text2") functions independently. In other words, all tags with the same initial characters in their ID (for example, "text1") should be linked in this way.

**Note that there could be many dozens of such lines of text, and thus dozens of such tags. Also, the number of alternate texts may vary from tag to tag, as in the revised first tag above.**

Also, how can I store each element's current text in cache, so that users who return to the page will still see the text personalized for them?

Much thanks in advance,
Brad

Comment: ID's are supposed to be unique y'know.. why not use different ID's/a class instead?

Answer (score 1):

I changed IDs to be unique. I also changed alt attributes to differ last element.

http://jsfiddle.net/H2yeR/

```
I <i class="alt1" id="text0" data-text='["like","love"]'>like</i> <i class="alt1" id="text1" data-text='["her","you"]'>her</i>, but I don't know <i class="alt2" id="text2" data-text='["him","you"]'>him</i>.

$('.alt1').click(function () {
    $('.alt1').each(function(i,e){
        swapText($(e));
    });
});
$('.alt2').click(function () {
    swapText($(this));
});

function swapText(alt) {
    var texts = alt.data('text');
    var current_text = alt.text();
    if(current_text==texts[0]) {
        alt.text(texts[1]);
    } else {
        alt.text(texts[0]);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I wrote more "universal" script. I use 2 class names for each element: alt and text where  is group number.

http://jsfiddle.net/mattydsw/H2yeR/2/

```
$('.alt').click(function () {
    var className = $(this).attr("class");
    className = className.split(' ');
    className = className[1];
    $('.alt.'+className).each(function(i,e){
        swapText($(e));
    });
});

function swapText(alt) {
    var texts = alt.data('text');
    var currentText = alt.text();
    var currentIdx = alt.data('i');
    if(currentIdx==undefined) {
        currentIdx = 0;
    }
    currentIdx = (currentIdx+1) % texts.length;
    alt.data('i',currentIdx);
    alt.text(texts[currentIdx]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, matty! See revisions above for clarification of the problem.

Comment: Thanks again; we're getting there! Three clarifications:

1) I need the function to run for all elements of class "alt" onload, so that each populates with the first text in its data-index.

2) I think I want to use IDs, after all. Can we change the function so that any two or more elements with IDs that are the same except for the last letter (e.g., id="text1a" and id="text1b" etc.) will change simultaneously upon click?

3) Can I somehow store each element's current text in cache, so that users who return to the page will still see the text personalized for them?